# jQuery problem in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I've got some code which when you click a button it populates the text of a textbox and then prepends another button to that div.

It works in all browsers except IE where it gives a javascript error.

The only way I can easily explain is by using my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ChiBlaaa/5buQt/)

If you use that in any browser apart from IE and click the `Book now` select a date and then another button will appear `Submit`.

This is the correct behaviour but if you use IE then as soon as you select a date there's a javascript error `Unexpected call to method or property access`

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is caused by this line:

```
$(".dupeadultcost").html($(this).parent().siblings().find(".adultcost").html());
```

As there is a textbox with a class of dupeadultcost this is blowing up in IE. If you only want to set the span I suggest you use:

```
$("span.dupeadultcost").html($(this).parent().siblings().find(".adultcost").html());
```

Working example - http://jsfiddle.net/d9TP8/1/

Comment: Just to clarify: the problem is that you can't directly set the `innerHTML` of textbox, it's meaningless.. while other browsers just ignore it, IE will report it as one of its cryptic errors. :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with these two lines

```
 $(".dupeadultcost").html($(this).parent().siblings().find(".adultcost").html());
```

$(".excursionSubmitButton").prependTo($(this).parent()).show(); // show form submit button

You need to replace class slectors (e.g. .dupeadultcost to id selectors #txtAdultcost) and it will work